# Lombok issues with Java 8

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, java-8, lombok

I just upgrade to Intellij idea 14 and Java 8 and I had on mind to upgrade my project to Java version 8 as well, to start using some new features. But After configure the Intellij properly to use Java 8 I have still the issue with Lombok. Looks like there´s a conflict between Java 8 and lombok because now my `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations do not work anymore.

The version of lombok is 1.10.8. Any suggestions?

Comment: According to the changelog, it should work with Java 8 since version 1.12.2: _PLATFORM: Initial JDK8 support, without affecting existing support for JDK6 and 7. Issue #451. While lombok will now work on JDK8 / javac8, and netbeans 7.4 and up, lombok does not (yet) support new language features introduced with java8, such as lambda expressions. Support for these features will be added in a future version._

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I had a old version of lombok, now that I update to 1.14 everything works fine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Lombok supports Java 8, and has done so since version 1.12.2.

---

**Long answer**

Lombok supports Java 8, and has done so since version 1.12.2 (October 10th, 2013) according to the [changelog](http://projectlombok.org/changelog.html):

> **PLATFORM:** Initial JDK8 support, without affecting existing support for JDK6 and 7. Issue #451. While lombok will now work on JDK8 / javac8, and netbeans 7.4 and up, lombok does not (yet) support new language features introduced with java8, such as lambda expressions. Support for these features will be added in a future version.

Since then further Java 8 support has been implemented:

- v1.12.6 (March 6th, 2014)

  > **PLATFORM:** Initial JDK8 support for eclipse's alpha support in kepler. Issue #597
- v1.14.0 "Branching Cobra" (May 27th, 2014)

  > **BUGFIX:** Usage of @SneakyThrows with a javac from JDK8 with -target 1.8 would result in a post compiler error. Issue #655
  >   **BUGFIX:** Major work on improving support for JDK8, both for javac and eclipse.
- v1.14.6 (September 2nd, 2014)

  > **BUGFIX:** Usage of val would break starting with JDK8 release 1.8.0_20. Issue #731

In other words, the newest version of Lombok should be able to work with Java 8 fairly well, and since version 1.12.2, Java 8 code without the new language features should work.

---

**EDIT**: As [Roel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12634/roel-spilker) pointed out, there is currently (8th january 2015) an [open bug](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/775) specifying that one specific Lombok feature (`val`) stopped working for 1.14.8.

This bug was closed 16th November 2015.

Comment: Well, there is a [report](https://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/detail?id=740) that a later version of Java or Lombok might have reintroduced the problem...

Comment: @RoelSpilker Well spotted. I will edit my answer to include this information.

Comment: We haven't had any subsequent reports, so the issue is closed as far as I'm concerned.