# lombok annotation is not recognized by intellij with Java 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, lombok

Anybody can tell me why using intellij with Java 8 the IDE cannot detect the getters and setters methods created by lombok annotation @Getter @Setter?. I had to install a specific plugin of lombok to make it works. With Java 7 everything was fine. I just want an explanation if somebody knows.

Regards.

Comment: I have difficulties understanding what the difference between this question and [your older question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27824973/2711488) is.

Comment: The old one was about issues becuase the lombok version. This one is between lombok + Intellij + Java 8

Comment: You are using the work “issue” as “cause of the problem” rather than “the problem you want to solve”. All I can see is that you still have the same problem and one attempt to solve it failed, which indicates that your assumption about what the “issue” (cause of the problem) is might have been wrong. So you still have the same “issue” (problem) and there is no use in opening a new question for the same problem for every assumption about its cause.

Comment: Again, one problem is between java 8 and the version that I had of lombok, 0.10.8 now with the 0.14 it´s solved. And the other is with Intellij

Comment: Could you tro to explain more about what differs between your other question, the one that I answered? Because it is really hard to spot the difference. I don't really understand it.

Comment: The other question was a problem with the lombok version and Java 8, upating the version of lombok it´s fixed. Now my question here, is why after update to Java 8 I need to install a lombook plugin on my intellij to make my IDE understand the getter and setters methods, when with Java 7 was not necesary

Comment: Do you have annotation processing enabled in your project? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-annotation-processing.html

Comment: I did nothing special, the thing is that with Java 7 was recognized and with 8 no.